# While working with ffmpeg: Created function in C file and after compilation with NDK accessing from android activity, getting signal 11 error

Tags: java, android, c, ffmpeg, android-ndk

After successfully fire command `ndk-build` I got .so file in my libs folder, then after some changes in gradle file I got native_libs.xml .idea/libraries folder.

Now I am accessing c function from my java code/ android activity. I am getting `signal 11` error

My code is

C file

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <android/log.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "libavcodec/avcodec.h"
#include "libavformat/avformat.h"

#define LOG_TAG "mylib"
#define LOGI(...)  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, LOG_TAG, __VA_ARGS__)
#define LOGE(...)  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, LOG_TAG, __VA_ARGS__)


//JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_xxx_xxx_activities_SplashActivity_logFileInfo(JNIEnv * env, jobject this, jstring filename);

jint Java_com_xxx_xxx_activities_TutorialsActivity_logFileInfo(JNIEnv * env, jobject this, jstring filename)
{
    av_register_all();

    AVFormatContext *pFormatCtx;
    const jbyte *str;
    str = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, filename, NULL);

    if(avformat_open_input(&pFormatCtx, str, NULL, NULL)!=0)
    {
        LOGE("Can't open file '%s'\n", str);
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        LOGI("File was opened\n");
        LOGI("File '%s', Codec %s",
            pFormatCtx->filename,
            pFormatCtx->iformat->name
        );
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Loading and try to access method in java code is

```
private static native int logFileInfo(String filename);


    static {
        System.loadLibrary("framegrabber");
    }
```

In OnCreate of activity

```
logFileInfo(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

Finally error at point  `logFileInfo(file.getAbsolutePath());` is

```
A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x106e in tid 8905 (Thread-20972)
```

Please replay if you have any solution, Thanking in advance.

Comment: I think you have logcat's output filtering on. There should be a stack trace in the output after the 'fatal signal' line, which is visible if you select 'No filters' in logcat.

Comment: There is no filter for logcat, I can get other errors stack trace. its weird problem. I think its because of file size in input. size is more than 20 mb.

Comment: Can you tell whether it is `logFileInfo()` or `file.getAbsolutePath()` that is crashing?